# Inactive button in UIAlert View

Tags: iphone, button, uialertview

In my iphone-app, I have a "Share" button in my Navigation bar, that pops up a UIAlertView with the options "Twitter" and "Facebook". When a user has already sent something to Twitter, I don't want him to be able to sent it again.

One way of preventing this, is to just remove the Twitter button from that Alert. This makes the Alert kind of inconsistent/unpredictable, and I would rather 'grey out' the Twitter button.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are doing, you should use an UIActionSheet.  It follows the HIG and then you can control the UX a bit better.

When you tap share, just create the action sheet with whatever options you want to allow the user to select.

Comment: Actually, I think this question is valid for the UIActionSheet as well: as far as I know, there is no 'grey' / 'inactive' property to a button in the 'sheet either